# I have an aluminium wheel of 6KG which I need to power up to 100 RPM

Tags: motor, dc

What power and kind of motor do I need?
Is it feasible to run from a 12 Volt battery/solar panel? 
I need a controller that will allow setting speed increments of 0.1 RPM

Sorry if this is a very simple question for here

Comment: You could do it with a stepper motor, if you took some precautions.. but... what on earth are you doing if you need to spin an aluminium wheel of 6 kg? (Yes, that's kg with small letters, not **K**elvin **G**ravitational-constant).

Comment: Friction loss of bearings and available current from power source needs to be selected. 0.1/100 velocity control requires a tach, or quadrature encoder.  Any motor will need pulleys to match RPM/V rating

Comment: Much of the answer also depends on the wheel diameter. You have to specify that.

Comment: does the wheel touch anything? how long is the ramp-up time?

Comment: you could cut pockets into the rim and use the 12V to run a compressor that would blow air at the rim of the wheel to make it spin

Comment: The diameter of the wheel is 1.2 metres. It only has to spin. It doesn't touch anything

Comment: Tony, is a car battery enough current?

Comment: The wheel is heavy for a reason Harry! And yes ok kg!

Comment: This is primarily a question about mechanical engineering, not electrical engineering. The amount of power required to spin a wheel at a specific speed will depend primarily on how well the wheel is balanced, and what type of bearings are used to support it.

Comment: "The wheel is heavy for a reason Harry!" And apparently this reason is not for us to know.

Answer (score 3):

The inertia of that uniform disc is
$$J=\frac{1}{2}\cdot m\cdot r^2=\frac{1}{2}\cdot6\,\mathrm{kg}\cdot 0.6^2\,\mathrm{m^2} = 1.08\,\mathrm{kg\,m^2}$$
Let us assume you want to regulate your 0.1rpm within 1ms — it simply makes no sense to regulate that tightly in a much longer timeframe. That's 100rpm/s, or $$\alpha = 2\pi\frac{100}{60\,\mathrm{s}}\frac{1}{\mathrm{s}} = 10.5 \frac{1}{\mathrm{s^2}}$$
From that, you can calculate the required torque for that given acceleration.
$$M=J\cdot\alpha=11.3\,\mathrm{\frac{kg\,m^2}{s^2}} = 11.3\,\mathrm{Nm}$$
Let's assume all this happens at 100rpm disc speed, so the required power is
$$P=M\cdot\omega=11.3\,\mathrm{Nm}\cdot2\pi\frac{100}{60\,\mathrm{s}}=118\,\mathrm{W}$$
You have to make sure your drivetrain (including the solar panel, losses etc.) can both deliver that torque and that power.

Comment: would s/he only need 1.18W if the regulation was 0.1 RPM within 100 ms instead? Assuming zero friction / wind resistance / other parasitics. - Because it's a *strange* requirement to force on yourself. 0.1 RPM / 1 ms can result in unnecessarily much power required. I'm fully aware that the energy spent will be the same for X RPM.

Comment: Correct. Because if the regulation is slower, you need less torque and because of that, less power. But I don't think 0.1rpm in 100ms is anything reasonable. That would mean noone may even step near to the desk where this thing is mounted on.

Comment: Where are the dimensions stated?

Comment: In the question comments, after I had asked for it.